# Difference $i++ and ++$i when 0

Tags: php

I came along this script lately:

```
$i = 0;
$x = $i++; $y = ++$i;
print $x; print $y;
```

The output was `02`. I can imagine that you can't count +1 on `$i` with `++` while it is 0, but why does `$y` output as 2? And why isn't the output `11` or `01`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

post increment vs pre increment.

Post: Trailing `$i++` means that `$i` is returned and then incremented after.

Pre: Preceding `++$i` means that `$i` is incremented and that result is returned.

So `$x` is set to `0` (the initial value of `$i`) and then incremented. `$i` is now equal to `1`. Then `$i` is incremented again to `2` and that value is set in `$y`. So in the end, `$x=0` and `$y=2` and `$i=2`. Your code could be rewritten as:

```
$i=0;
//x, post increment, set x to i then increment after.
$x=$i;
$i=$i+1;

//y, pre increment, increment first and then set y to i.
$i=$i+1;
$y=$i;
```

Same thing applies to the decrement operator `--$i` and `$i--`.